# Are Shiva & Vishnu etymologically connected?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, sanskrit, etymology, language

It has always struck me as interesting, or perhaps odd, that the root phonemes of Shiva, [sh]+[v], are the reverse of the root phonemes of Vishnu, [v]+[sh]. Is there any accounting for this?

Comment: These type of questions are entertained on this site I Think.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Apologies, I used the International Phonetic Alphabet of linguists. I have changed it to generic Anglicization: 'sh' & 'v'.

Comment: The question is on-topic. Don't worry. :)

Comment: Don't worry about the troll, we have a few around.

Comment: What troll?  

Comment: @RubelliteFae the first answerer.

Comment: Without recognition, it doesn't exist. ;)

Comment: No. 'Shiva' is made with श  ś (not ष ṣ ), and 'Vishnu' is made with ष ṣ (not श ś ) . श ś is a palatal Sh sound, and ष ṣ is retroflex Sh sound. In English alphabet there is no symbol  for श and ष , so we write both as Sh, as using phonetic symbols like ś and ṣ always is not convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anurag Singh commented:

> No. 'Shiva' is made with श ś (not ष ṣ ), and 'Vishnu' is made with ष ṣ (not श ś ) . श ś is a palatal Sh sound, and ष ṣ is retroflex Sh sound. In English alphabet there is no symbol for श and ष , so we write both as Sh, as using phonetic symbols like ś and ṣ always is not convenient.

For linguistic reference, in IPA `श ś` can be the *voiceless postalveolar (nonretroflex) fricatives* `/ɕ/ or /ʃ/` while `ष ṣ` is the *voiceless retroflex fricative*, `/ʂ/`.